# Cake Model Association

Tags: cakephp

I'm not quite sure how to accomplish this with CakePHP. I have 3 models:

```
ReportType: id/name

Example Data:

1/Report1
2/Report2

ReportData: id/report_type_id (matches ReportType)/row_number (matches row number in CSV)/data

Example Data:

1/1/1/longstring1
2/1/1/longstring1-2
3/1/1/longstring1-3
4/1/2/longstring2
5/1/3/longstring3
6/1/4/longstring4

PaymentData: id/report_type_id (matches ReportType)/row_number (matches row number in CSV)/payment_amount

Example Data:

1/1/1/5
2/1/2/6
3/1/3/78
4/1/5/9

ReportType:
HasMany: ReportData, PaymentData
```

Example Query:

```
$this->ReportType->contain('PaymentData');
$payment_data = $this->ReportType->find('first');
```

Right now, this would yield:

```
[ReportType]
     id => 1
     name => Report1

[PaymentData]
    [0] =>
        id => 1
        report_type_id => 1
        row_number => 1
        payment_amount => 5
    [1] =>
        id => 1
        report_type_id => 1
        row_number => 2
        payment_amount => 6

    (and so on)
```

What I would like to be able to do is for each PaymentData row, be able to match the row where report_type_id and row_number match in ReportData (I only need 1 row). For example, I would like the data returned to be:

```
[ReportType]
    id => 1
    name => Report1

[PaymentData]
    [0] =>
        id => 1
        report_type_id => 1
        row_number => 1
        payment_amount => 5

        [ReportData] => (matched by report_type_id and row_number for PaymentData above)
            [0] =>
                id => 1
                report_type_id => 1
                row_number => 1
                data => longstring1
    [1] =>
        id => 1
        report_type_id => 1
        row_number => 2
        payment_amount => 6

        [ReportData] => (matched by report_type_id and row_number for PaymentData above)
            [0] =>
                id => 4
                report_type_id => 1
                row_number => 2
                data => longstring2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do the match inside the `contain`:

```
$payment_data = $this->ReportType->find('first', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'PaymentData' => array(
            'ReportData' => array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'PaymentData.report_type_id' => 'ReportData.report_type_id',
                    'PaymentData.row_numbrer' => 'ReportData.row_number'
                )
            )
        )
    )
));
```

Assuming that `ReportType` has many `PaymentData` and this one has many `ReportData`